# Wearing a mask on Shabbos

Tags: halacha, shabbat

Any sources or psaks about wearing a protective mask outdoors on Shabbos? Is it allowed where there is no eruv?

Comment: Why wouldn't it be allowed?

Comment: https://oukosher.org/halacha-yomis/is-it-permissible-to-wear-a-surgical-mask-and-gloves-outdoors-on-shabbos-in-an-area-where-there-is-no-eiruv/

Comment: I don't really understand how surgical gloves or masks can be called clothing. No one wants to be wearing them, they aren't stylish, and they provide no immediate tangible benefit. It's like hooking a bottle of Purell to your wrist: convenient, but not clothing.

Comment: The MB brings the Gra about protection as a refuah...see the teshuva I cited

Comment: @doubleAA while I agree with you about masks, I think surgical gloves are different. I personally carry them around with me frequently in the winter time since I suffer from dry skin. I wear them often the whole day, especially if I'm a little sick and washing my hands a lot. I wear them until they break (which might be another halachic problem).

Comment: @Binyomin with all due respect, and with prayers for continued refuah for your hands, בטלה דעתך אצל כל אדם.

Comment: @DoubleAA I'm not exactly the only person who does this. I actually started after I saw other people in the streets doing this. We discussed this issue in kollel when we were learning O.C. 301 and a few people mentioned that when they forgot their regular gloves at home during the cold winter they would occasionally take disposable gloves from the shul (with permission!) to wear home. It works quite well. (If anybody asks, just say you're a follower of Michael Jackson fashion!) So while admittedly it's not so widespread, I'm not the only person doing it.

Comment: @sam that's for something that is magein. This isn't. There is no potential benefit that you feel or could feel now from this. Maybe next week your friend won't get sick. That's not magein. You have to get macroscopic benefit to matter halakhicaly. These are very difficult svaros people are relying on.

Comment: That's why Rav Weiss suggests to put hands in pockets to avoid any potential issue,but if you see someone doing it yeish al mi lismoch,especially if we hold there are no real reshus harabam today(yes ,I know very controversial).

Comment: @sam no real reshus harabim is just relevant to the concerns of taking it off and such. If it's not clothing there's nothing to talk about. especially if you are sick and the mask is to protect others: how is that possibly called magein???

Answer (score 8):

Rav Asher Weiss wrote a teshuva concerning wearing gloves and a mask in a reshus harabim in [a kuntres on the Corona Virus](http://forum.otzar.org/download/file.php?id=86504). It's siman 9. He comes out to be lenient for both, but suggests it may be better to put one's hands in pockets and use the clothing one is wearing to block their mouth to avoid any issues.

Comment: He did mention one reason he was willing to lean towards the lenient side is relying on the centuries out of date fact there is no real reshus harabim anymore. That certainly makes a difference in some of the hardest hit areas.

Answer (score 5):

Per article in [theyeshivaworld](https://www.theyeshivaworld.com/news/featured/1852946/7-new-rulings-from-hagaon-harav-chaim-kanievsky-regarding-corona.html) Rabbi Chaim Kanievsky ruled that currently, since one is obligated to wear a mask due to the guidelines – it is considered a malbush [article of clothing] and one must wear them even on Shabbos and there is no concern of carrying.

Comment: Is there precedent for required wearing of non garments making them garments? (Perhaps yellow stars in the Holocaust?)

Comment: @DoubleAA The Rama talks about yellow... not exactly stars but same idea https://www.sefaria.org/Shulchan_Arukh%2C_Orach_Chayim.301.23

Comment: @Heshy nice, but that has to be connected at least superficially to actual clothing

Comment: Was he actually paskening that, or was he answering a theoretical question?

Comment: @donielf I do not think such a question is theoretical, so why do you think his answer is theoretical?

Comment: @GershonGold Because he himself says he's not a posek, yet people take him as one.

Comment: Doesn't sound better than a slaves chosem. Unless he thinks the obligation to wear will take away the shema yishlof.

Comment: Shabbos Bemah Isha

Answer (score 2):

This was received from someone who heard from someone who... Take it with a grain of salt. I’m only posting it because it conforms with the opinion of Rav Chaim Kanievsky posted here previously.

> In order for one to wear a mask outside on Shabbos where there is no eiruv, one must wear the mask in its usual position over his mouth and nose--and not lower it to his chin or below—notwithstanding that it may be uncomfortable. Otherwise, the mask would constitute a masui—and cannot be worn outside on Shabbos. This p’sak has been confirmed by HaRav Shmuel Kamenetsky, Shlita.

Answer (score 0):

Not a Psak Halacha. Just theoretical.

Based off the Gemara in Shabbos 59, it seems that (aside from pkuach nefesh) it'd be mutar to go out wearing a anti-virus mask, because (it's not a masui/burden) the folks wearing it are respectable people (consider/care about themselves) and therefore they wouldn't take it off in public (due to carona & a 6ft distance protocol). Also, aside from it not being a masui, there are masks being made that are essentially tachshitim/ornaments and thus render them Mutar as well...

Aside from Dina D'malchusah Dina i'm not sure. Although the LAW where i live, is that one may not be in public without a mask.

Comment: I respectfully disagree with some of your assumptions. Wearing masks aren't comfortable- no one likes wearing it for no reason. And I see here in Israel how many people take them off once they are out of range of other people. This is true even for the nice looking decorative masks- people take them off to get air, to adjust their glasses etc. I'm not addressing what they should be doing, nor how the law affects the question.

Comment: Pikuach Nefesh and Dina Demalkhuta don't matter since you don't need to go outside.

Answer (score 0):

[Rav Yitzchak Abadi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yitzchak_Abadi) ruled that wearing a surgical mask on shabbos outside is prohibited.

Comment: Where did you see this?